# Heterogeneous Oracle to SQL Server: Using "IS NULL" in Where clause for Update statement

Tags: sql-server, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, heterogeneous-services

I am having trouble with using the IS NULL condition in an Update statement executed on an SQL Server 2000 database via an Oracle Database (11.2.0.4) using an ODBC heterogeneous connection.

Example of update statement that will not work.

```
UPDATE TABLENAME@RemoteSQLServer2000
  SET "ColumnName" = 'SomeValue'
WHERE "AnotherColumnName" IS NULL;
```

Result:

> ORA-02070: database RemoteSQLServer2000 does not support  IS NULL in this context

However, the following statement works fine:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLENAME@RemoteSQLServer2000
 WHERE "AnotherColumnName" IS NULL;
```

Does anyone have an idea about what I can do to make this work? Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Could you try working around this by using an expression like `coalesce(AnotherColumnName, 'null') = 'null'`, avoiding the `IS NULL` syntax?

Comment: @MickMnemonic Thanks for the response. I tried your suggestion and received the following response:
"ORA-02070: database RemoteSQLServer2000 does not support COALESCE in this context"
I had similar luck with several other variations of the statement including inline queries and other functions like length and concat.

Comment: Does _any_ `UPDATE` with a `WHERE` clause in it work against the target DB?

Comment: @MickMnemonic Yes. I am only having trouble when attempting to filter based on null values.
For example the following statement will work fine: 
UPDATE TABLENAME@RemoteSQLServer2000
  SET "ColumnName" = 'SomeValue'
WHERE "AnotherColumnName" = 5

Comment: Interesting. Did you also try a direct equals comparison (`AnotherColumnName = NULL`)? There is an `ANSI_NULLS` (=false) option which allows you to use this syntax in SQLServer (even though `IS NULL` should also work when ANSI nulls are disabled).

Comment: @MickMnemonic I did try a direct comparison, just in case, but no luck. Not sure how to set the ANSI_NULLS option via a heterogeneous query.

Comment: You could try executing the update via `DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH`: `BEGIN
DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE@RemoteSQLServer2000 ('UPDATE TABLENAME SET ColumnName = ''SomeValue'' WHERE AnotherColumnName IS NULL');
END;
/`. Unfortunately it means you'd need to wrap it into a PL/SQL block, but might be worth a try anyways.

Comment: @MickMnemonic This work great. I will document as answer.

Comment: Nice to hear you got it working!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @MickMnemonic and another consultant, we were able to find a solution.

Oracle has a package that allows you to execute SQL from an application to an SQL Server database. This function will allow you to successfully execute a statement like the one mentioned in the question where you are filtering on NULL values.  [Oracle Documentation for DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/gateways.112/e12069/ch3.htm#GMSWN200)

Following is an example of the new code that works.

```
DECLARE
   num_rows   INTEGER;
BEGIN
   num_rows :=
      DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE@RemoteSQLServer2000 (
         'UPDATE TABLENAME SET "ColumnName" = ''SomeValue'' WHERE AnotherColumnName IS NULL');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your where clause instead of where AnotherColumnName  is null

Where AnotherColumnName || 'x' = 'x'

Comment: Where AnotherColumnName || 'x' = 'x' doesn't work, and it gives a similar error "database <sqlserverdatabase> doesn't not support || in this context", but an interesting observation. Thank you.